# Angular - Conditional Custom Validator on a FormGroup Inside of a FormGroup

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, validation

I have a form that needs to check if one of a group of checkboxes is checked if a dropdown has a specific value. I have a validator that works on the checkboxes, but I only need it to check if the dropdown is a specific value. Below is the form and validation code. I've tried having the validator bind like this.requireCheckboxesValidator.bind(this), but then it just seems to ignore the validator

```
  readonly closeFormGroup: FormGroup;


  constructor(
    formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    this.closeFormGroup = formBuilder.group({
      notes: [null],
      reason: [1, Validators.required],
      checkBoxGroup: new FormGroup({
        checkBox1: new FormControl(false),
        checkBox2: new FormControl(false),
        checkBox3: new FormControl(false),
        checkBox4: new FormControl(false),
        checkBox5: new FormControl(false),
      } ,this.requireCheckboxesValidator())
    });
  }
  public requireCheckboxesValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return function validate(formGroup: FormGroup) {
      let checked = 0;
      console.log(formGroup);
      Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
         const control = formGroup.controls[key];

         if (control.value === true) {
           checked++;
         }
       });

      if (checked < 1) {
        return {
          requireCheckboxesToBeChecked: true,
        };
      }

      return null;
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a different approach. 
You can subscribe to `valueChanges` of your dropdown field and then if the specific value that is selected is what you expect, you can use `addValidator` to add the certain validator to your checkboxes form control. 
I also like your idea of adding a custom validator (definitely the better approach) and it should actually work in that way as well. From what I understand you're trying to add the validator for the checkboxes only if the dropdown has a specific value ? In that case you need to change your logic to something like:

```
      Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
         const control = formGroup.controls[key];

         if (control.value === true) {
           checked++;
         }
        let dropdownValue = undefined;
        if (key === 'dropdownFormControlKey') {
            dropdownValue = control.value;
        }
       });

      if (checked < 1) { // --- Add check to also see if the dropdown's value is what you expect and only then return the error
        return {
          requireCheckboxesToBeChecked: true,
        };
      }

      return null;
    };
```

- Also, I would suggest not to define the validator function in your component, instead follow this article to see a proper approach - https://angular.io/guide/form-validation